# Unable to load .mha files in ITK

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, image-processing, itk

I have successfully installed ITK and VTK with python wrapping and can be imported in python. I have installed them for .mha file processing and even after installing both ITK and VTK, problem still persists. It shows the following error:

[image: Unable to Load .mha Files]

So, guys is there any idea how can I load .mha volumetric images in python for further image processing. Or is there any way to process .mha files.

Even I try to call any module related to ITK then it shows the following error:[image: Unable to call supporting Libraries]

This happen with all ITK supporting libraries. So how to get rid of this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was successfully able to load .mha images in Python using [SimpleITK](http://www.simpleitk.org/).

The installation instructions are listed [here](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/SimpleITK/GettingStarted), and the documentation can be found [here](http://www.simpleitk.org/SimpleITK/help/documentation.html).

After that the .mha image can be easily readed:

```
import SimpleITK
inputImage = SimpleITK.ReadImage( your_image.mha )
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I also tried SimpleITK but I found the ITK was not buildup properly so both ITK and SimpleITK both even after installation were not working properly. Readimage is working but if I invloke any other related function or module then it shows error.